# How can I clear the appcache on the Google Chrome iPad app?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

I've written a little HTML5 based web app that I am trying to debug on the iPad using the Chrome for iPad app.

I have added a `cache.manifest` file to my app which has some heavy caching in it of most static resources however since I am now wanting to debug the app I need a way to clear this cache.

I know that on Chrome for Mac you can use: `chrome://appcache-internals/` however this page does not exist in the iPad app of Chrome.

The regular "Clear Browsing Data" does not empty the appcache —*at least not in my case*.

Does anyone know how I can clear the appcache for the Chrome iPad app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. It seems to have a delay as I have cleared the Chrome cache and then cleared the Safari cache (in settings), and then maybe 12 hours later it will eventually give me the new version of the offline app.

The other (more drastic) option is to uninstall and re-install chrome. Not really a long term solution for end users.

If only Safari would introduce a better cache solution.